# Tensorflow behaves differently between GPU and CPU

Tags: tensorflow, gpu, cpu

I modified the Tensorflow tutorial example for beginners by adding a hidden layer. The recognition rate obtained by running on GPU is ~95%. But when running in cpu-only mode, I can get ~40%. Does anybody know why the same python code behaves so differently? Thanks.

Weiguang

Comment: Why would you expect both to slow by the same margin?

Comment: I didn't mean speed.

Comment: Ah, I misunderstood.